# Tornado hello_world test returns 599

Tags: python, tornado

I am using Tornado 4.4 with CPython 2.7.

I copied:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

from http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html to hello.py and then:

```
import hello

class TestHelloApp(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        return hello.make_app()

    def test_homepage(self):
        response = self.fetch('/')
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.body, 'Hello, world')
```

from http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/testing.html to test_hello.py

And when I run:

`python -m tornado.test.runtests test_hello`

I am getting:

`AssertionError: 599 != 200`.

Either I am missing something or the Tornado docs/code need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've mistakenly indented the code in `hello.py`. This line should not be indented at all:

```
def make_app():
```

That is to say, in the Tornado docs `make_app` is a module-level function, but in your code you've made it a member of MainHandler.

Comment: My bad, thanks Jessie for pointing it out. I am still getting that 599 though.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I was executing this test in VirtualBox/Ubuntu 14.04. And it turns out this is very important since I am not getting that 599 when I run it directly in OSX or VirtualBox/Debian Jessie. I am still perplexed though since Ubuntu 14.04 is derived from Jessie and I was expecting similar behaviour.